# “Still wanted” vs “still want”

Tags: grammar, american-english, tenses, backshifting

In the following text, the speaker has not yet had dinner.

> I still wanted to get some climbing in before dinner.

Does that sentence indicate the speaker still intends to go climbing, or only that they intended to do so in the past?

Comment: You need more context. The use of the past tense could signal a more polite way of expressing a current desire: *I still want to get some climbing in before dinner.* Or it could mean that this was a want in the past.

Comment: @TinfoilHat As you say, the context is missing and the OP's question can't be answered without knowing more.  For example: Marsha came into the room and asked me to help prepare the evening meal. I was reluctant; I still wanted to get some climbing in before dinner."  On the other hand: Marsha came into the room and asked me to help prepare the evening meal. I declined, saying "I still want to get some climbing in before dinner."

Answer (score 3):

In such contexts it's not uncommon for native speakers to "backshift" a statement about what they [currently<sup>1</sup>] want.

This puts a certain amount of "distance" between the speaker and his words. Compare ***Can** I have X?* and ***Could** I have X?*, where the "more distant" second version comes across as more formal.

The speaker is thus being slightly "self-effacing". Stereotypically, Anglophones sometimes portray this tendency in speakers of other languages by having them say things like *Could **this humble servant** help you?* rather than *Can **I** help you?* (it's self-effacing to avoid the first person singular pronoun).

---

TL;DR: Past tense is often used instead of present tense in such contexts. For example, initiating a conversation with *I **wanted** to ask you something* rather than *I **want** to ask you...* is quite natural - especially if the addressee has higher status than the speaker.

---

<sup>1</sup> As pointed out in comments, OP hasn't presented a full context. So it's at least *possible* the speaker / writer is actually using the past tense *literally* (i.e. - referring to *an actual time in the past* when he had that desire). The important point is we *can* use past tense to "obliquely" refer to a *current* desire.

Comment: Compare "I will say this: you are right" with the softened "I would say this: you are not wrong."

Comment: More directly / bluntly, ***I say / I'm saying** that you're wrong!*

Comment: I appreciate the analysis! But am somewhat confused by it :) Are you saying that the speaker in the original sentence used past tense (wanted) but the intension was still present tense?

Comment: @JorgeBarreto It **could** simply be the past of narration; without seeing the full context, we can’t say. It’s like how *I will say this: you are right* really means *I am willing to say that you are right*, and how *I would say this: you are not wrong* really means *I might be willing to say that you are not wrong*; nothing but the present is involved in either. We have many nuanced ways to “soften” things in English by playing with modals like these. Think how *That will be John* and *That must be John* both express your current opinion that it **is** John right now: no future and no past.

Comment: Back to the original, *I still wanted* is past tense. But with politeness in English, it often means "I'll join you for dinner soon, but since I planned to exercise first, I actually still want to do that first." That means I'm not saying no to dinner now, only that my plan (if you'll *accommodate* me) was to exercise and I still want to. Okay with you?

Comment: @YosefBaskin: It's potentially misleading to call it "past tense". Imho, English only has ***two*** tenses - "Present" and "Not Present". And actual native Anglophones don't much like Present Tense anyway. Especially *continuous;* McDonald's slogan ***I'm loving it*** was largely based on the fact that those words are inexplicably "peculiar" and hence "memorable" to native Anglophones, but they're unremarkable to people who speak "Indian English". (That PR advertising campaign reflects its "globalist" aspirations more than most! :).

Comment: ...that's to say, your "if you'll accommodate me" is "close enough". But this isn't something that can be usefully analysed in terms of "past - present - future" having any connection to "the arrow of time". It's basically ***here = now = real*** on one side (referenced by "present" tense"), and everything else is referenced by circumlocution.

Comment: Rather, it might be better to say English has only past and non-past; of that there's substantial evidence.  But we digress.